# group algebra and its center

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, group-rings

Let *F* be a field and *G* group so the group algebra is defined as:

$F[G] = {\sum_{g\in G} c_{g} g: c_{g} \in F, g\in G}$

take the element $a= \sum_{g \in G} g$, clearly $a\in G$. Can I say that *a* is in the center of $F[G]$, i.e *a* comutes with every element in $F[G]$

Comment: Yes. Also, hopefully you're working over a finite group. Otherwise, $a$ might not be well-defined.

Comment: yes it is finite group. but how can I prove it? G is not abelian

Comment: $a$ is NOT in $G$.  The only things in $G$ are of the form $1\cdot g$

Comment: but *a* is the sum og *G*'s elements and *G* is closed

Comment: @Napu $G$ is *not* closed under $+$. The operation $+$ is something defined on all of $R[G]$. $G$ has its own operation, which we should write as $\cdot$. You have that $g\cdot h\in G $ if $g,h\in G$, but $1g+1h$ won't be in $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. $\sum_{g \in G}g$ is a central element of $F[G]$ assuming that $G$ is finite and this sum is well-defined.

Let $\sum_{g \in G} a_g g \in F[G]$, then $(\sum_{h \in G} h)(\sum_{g \in G} a_g g)=\sum_{g \in G}a_g (\sum_{h \in G}hg)$. Now the map $G \to G, h \mapsto hg$ is a bijection, as is the map $G \to G, h \mapsto gh$, so we have $\sum_{h \in G}hg=\sum_{h \in G} gh$.
Thus $\sum_{g \in G}a_g(\sum_{h \in G} hg)=\sum_{g \in G}a_g(\sum_{h \in G} gh)=(\sum_{g \in G}a_g g)(\sum_{h \in G} h)$. This shows that $\sum_{h \in G}h$ is central.